# socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, 500-error

```
fs.file-max = 70000
```

added into `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
nginx       soft    nofile   10000
nginx       hard    nofile  30000
```

added into `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
```

adding this into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` leads to an issue while reloading nginx:

```
# systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
```

File `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` after adding looks:

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


#this is added
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  8192;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

**Update:**
Editing the nginx.service file

```
systemctl edit --full nginx.service
```

and adding `LimitNOFILE=10000`
did not help

**SOLVED**

I had to add `worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;` to the file `/etc/nginx/ulimit.global_params`